# check the file and add a new string

Tags: file, go, readfile, writefile

My goal is to check all the lines of the file (there is one word per line) and if the string is not present in the whole file, I have to add it at the bottom.

The problem is that the "is_Cursor" loop changes my "tx.Data" and therefore I have to give the for loop several times and start again several times from the beginning

```
    fileWrite, err := os.OpenFile(fileName, os.O_APPEND|os.O_RDWR, os.ModeAppend)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    defer fileWrite.Close()

    fileRead, err := os.Open(fileName)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    defer fileRead.Close()
    isWrite := false

for is_Cursor {

    for i := 0; i < len(tx.Data) && i < maxMemoryTx; i++ {
            isWrite = false
            //scannerWrite := bufio.NewScanner(fileWrite)
            scannerRead := bufio.NewScanner(fileRead)

            for scannerRead.Scan() {
                fmt.Println(scannerRead.Text())
                if scannerRead.Text() == tx.Data[i].Type {
                    println("block")
                    isWrite = true
                }
            }
            if !isWrite {
                if scannerRead.Scan() == false {
                    println("new")
                    fileWrite.WriteString(tx.Data[i].Type)
                }
                if _, err := fileWrite.WriteString("\n"); err != nil {
                    log.Fatal(err)
                }
            }
        
        }
    //other
}
```

Where am I doing wrong?

how do i check and then insert in the file if necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> check all the lines of the file (there is one word per line) and if the string is not present in the whole file, I have to add it at the bottom.

---

Follow the instructions. Read all the words in the file. Then, add any new words at the end. For example,

```
func appendNewWords(fileName string, newWords []string) error {
    fileWords := make(map[string]bool)
    file, err := os.OpenFile(fileName, os.O_APPEND|os.O_RDWR, os.ModeAppend)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer file.Close()

    scnr := bufio.NewScanner(file)
    for scnr.Scan() {
        fileWords[scnr.Text()] = true
    }
    if err := scnr.Err(); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    wtr := bufio.NewWriter(file)
    for _, word := range newWords {
        if !fileWords[word] {
            fileWords[word] = true
            _, err := wtr.WriteString(word)
            if err != nil {
                return err
            }
            err = wtr.WriteByte('\n')
            if err != nil {
                return err
            }
        }
    }
    err = wtr.Flush()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    err = file.Close()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
```